# Hide discount box in Shopify Plus if cart items contain these products

Tags: scripting, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-api

Hoping someone can help with this...

We have two types of product in our store, outlet and premium.

On the checkout page, we are losing a large volume of sales as customers are trying to enter a discount code for items which are already heavily discounted.

Is it possible to create a Shopify Plus script that will..

- Work out if the items in the cart are part of the outlet collection, or are tagged 'outlet'
- If so, hide the discount code box

Seems simple but I can't find a good answer anywhere..

thanks!

Comment: A Shopify script for `line_items` – or any other type – won't be able to hide/show elements on the page, it can only modify the objects within its scope.

However, it should be able to identify items – based on a condition or more – and reject  applying a discount code to the identified items.

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkout.liquid` layout to remove that input based on current items in the cart.

```
{%- liquid
  assign hideDiscountBox = false
  assign productIdsToHideDiscountBox = "123456789012345,543210987654321,..."
  for item in checkout.line_items
    if productIdsToHideDiscountBox contains item.product_id
        assign hideDiscountBox = true
        break
    endif
  endfor
  if hideDiscountBox
    echo "<style>.order-summary__section--discount { display: none; }</style>"
  endif
-%}
```

Comment: Hi @vladimir 

Thanks so much for your suggestion, I'll give that a go and let you know if it works!